# Strange $_SESSION var behivor in PHP

Tags: php, session

I've been struggling with this for 2 days now.
the code below works perfect on my localhost `(WampServer Version 2.5, Apache v2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12)` but not on my host server.
I am trying to pass `$_SESSION` from one page to another (both files are under the same folder.) during a sign up for a new user.

```
page 1:(stepOne.php)
```

assign `$_SESSION['userid']:`

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once (dirname(__FILE__) .'/classes/data.php'); 
$_SESSION['userID'] = $user->id; /*user->id is set.*/
?>
```

page 2:(steps.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once (dirname(__FILE__) .'/classes/data.php');
$data = new data();
error_log("session at start=".print_r($_SESSION,true));
?>
```

result is:

```
[14-Jul-2015 23:31:40 America/Denver] session at start=Array
(
)
```

already checked:
`1.session_start()` on each page`.

`2.sessions are` enabled.

```
3.session.save_handler = files on php.ini

4.session.save_path = "/tmp" - I've created "tmp" folder
```

I also can't find the session file under the "tmp" folder.
Would appreciate any suggestions and answers

**UPDATE 15/7/15** - SOLVED
After checking with my host server figure out couple of things:

- there was an .htaccess that apparently pointed to a different php.ini then the one I wanted
- in this .htaccess there was a rule that redirect pages causing the $_SESSION to reset.

so,
What I've learnt from this:

1. Always check if you are pointing to the right php.ini
2. Search for .htaccess around ALL of your folders - there might be an old one that messing around the configurations.

Comment: can you just `include_once (dirname(__FILE__) .'/classes/data.php');` to `include_once ('classes/data.php');` and try again. That may possible that the directory you are getting may different and it may not showing error because of you may have turned errors off.

Comment: make sure that the tmp directory is writable by the user running the web server and ensure that the tmp directory is located on the root of the file system (or change /tmp in the session.save_path to a full absolute path to where your tmp directory is located)  that is probably the issue here. Also check the error logs on your web server for any hints as to what is going on.

Comment: @PratikSoni , tried that and i get "failed to open stream" thats way I include (dirname(__FILE__)..

Comment: @Orangepill modified the root /tmp to 0777 (just for the test) and change to full path in php.ini- still not working.

Comment: are session files being created in the temp directory? also make sure the hostname in the url isnt changed between calls. might be a good idea to do a phpinfo page to make sure your webserver is picking up your ini changes.

Comment: @Orangepill, actually they don't. I was with my server support and they cant really know why this is happening. as mentioned before I did changed the path to a full path.

Comment: try explicitly calling session_write_close... maybe that will reveal whats happening

Comment: @Orangepill, thanks.. already did that..didn't help. I did found that it points to a different php.ini from what I've expected. now with my server host, trying to figure it out

Comment: @Orangepill, thanks for your tips. it helped alot :)

Comment: Glad you resolved the problem. May I suggest that you post the solution as an answer below and mark it as 'accepted'. That way it's more likely to help others who have similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** 
After checking with my host server figure out couple of things:

1. there was an .htaccess that apparently pointed to a different
   php.ini then the one I wanted
2. in this .htaccess there was a rule that redirect pages causing the
   $_SESSION to reset.

so, What I've learnt from this:

- Always check if you are pointing to the right php.ini
- Search for .htaccess around ALL of your folders - there might be an old one that messing around the configurations.

Additional suggestions I've picked through my search of solution:

When using AJAX try add

> session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.yourWebsite.com')

; before session_start()